# angular directive of jquery crop plugin dimensions are off on mobile devices

Tags: jquery, angularjs, mobile, crop, directive

I've implemented 2 jquery crop plugins as custom directives in angularJS, Guillotine (https://github.com/matiasgagliano/guillotine) and Image Cropper (http://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/).

Both work correctly in retrieving crop dimensions (x, y, width, height) on desktop, but in mobile, although the crop dimensions are technically correct, the size of the image is not taken into account.  The cropped result is therefore only a small fragment of the desired crop area.

How do I fix this?

UPDATE:: I realized this is most likely a server issue.  For some reason, while the server correctly sets up a ratio to the original photo being cropped on desktop, it doesn't do so with images loaded from mobile.

Here's the (edited for brevity) angular directive that works with Guillotine.

```
    (function () {
        angular.module('Crop').directive('skCrop', ['$sce', '$route', '$cookieStore', 'putService', 'picService', 'deleteService', function($sce, $route, $cookieStore, putService, picService, deleteService) {
            return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: '/pic/crop.html',
            scope: {
                pic: '@',
            },
            link: function( scope, el, atts) {
                var picture = angular.element('#picture');
                var cropDims = {};

                scope.crop = function() {
                    var data =angular.element(el).find('img').guillotine('getData');
                    cropDims.x = data.x;
                    cropDims.y = data.y;
                    cropDims.width = data.w;
                    cropDims.height = data.h;
                    // $http PUT to server here
                };


                scope.$watch('pic', function () {
                    picture[0].onload = function () {
                        width = this.width;
                        height = this.height;
                        if (width > 0) {
                            picture.guillotine({
                                width: 500,
                                height: 500    
                            }); // end picture.guillotine
                        }


                    };// end picture.onload

                }); // end scope.$watch


            } // end link
        }; // end return

    }]);


})();
```

html fragment:

```
    <sk-crop pic="{{obj.user.picfull}}">
    </sk-crop>
```

skCrop template:

```
<section>
  <div class="img-container">
    <img id="picture" ng-src="{{trustSrc(pic)}}"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="clear()">Remove</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="crop()">Save</button>
  </div>
</section>
```

css:

```
    .img-container {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      max-width: 500px;
      margin-left: 0 auto;
      margin-right: 0 auto;
      display: block;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the data you get on the server and describe how it is used? Possibly the server side cropper is misinterpreting the scale.

I don't work with Angular, but keep in mind that the plugin should be removed and re-initialized if you change the source of the target image. So, if you put the initializer inside an observer you might be mounting several instances of the plugin if the image *src* changes.

Comment: The data that gets posted to the server are the crop dimensions as a JSON object. `code` {"x":95.99999999999999,"y":256,"width":768.0000000000001,"height":768.0000000000001} `code`.  I'm not sure about how the server is using the data.  I'll ask!

Comment: The *scale* and *angle* are missing there, 
Guillotine's output (through *getData*) is something like: `{ scale: 1.4, angle: 270, x: 10, y: 20, w: 400, h: 300 }`. Not applying the *scale* should be causing your problem of the size of the image not being taken into account.